# How to do a pop up screen in service now when we click on a button?

Tags: popup, servicenow

I am building a UI page in service now, I want to create a pop up screen in the middle of the page when a button is clicked.
That pop up screen should contain some information (documentation).
How can I implement it?

Answer (score 0):

I don't exactly understand what type of pop up you're looking for, but here goes.

You want to give an onclick function to your button, like this:

```
<button id='popUpButton' onclick='popUpFunc'>Click me!</button>


<script>
popUpFunc() {

     window.alert("sometext");

}

</script>
```

This will create a popup alert on the user's browser with whatever text you assign to the alert. You can also create a text node onclick like this

```
popUpFunc () {
    var info = document.createTextNode('sometext')
    document.getElementById('your body id').appendChild(info)
}
```

Hope this helps, feel free to ask away, although I am also quite new to this.